# Jquery file upload in rails on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery-fileupload plugin (https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails) for showing file upload progress in my rails app. The following code below works fine.

In my index.html.erb i have

```
  <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
  <div class="upload">
    {%=o.name%}
    <div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div></div>
  </div>
  </script>
```

In my projects js.coffee file i have

```
$('#import_form').fileupload
    dataType: "json"
    add: (e, data) ->
      data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", data.files[0]))
      $('#import_form').append(data.context)
      data.submit()
    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
```

But i want the upload to start when i click a button with id import_button instead of automatically. How can i achieve that ?

I tried doing the following, but i get the error message **"data is undefined"**

```
$('#import_form').fileupload
    dataType: "json"
    add: (e, data) ->       
      data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", data.files[0]))
      $('#import_form').append(data.context)
      $("#import_button").off("click").on "click", ->
        data.submit()
    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
```

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

One special callback is the `add` callback, as it provides a submit method for the data argument, that will start the file upload:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    add: function (e, data) {
       data.submit();
    }
});
```

It's from [jQuery Plugin Wiki](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API)

So if you don't want to start the upload automatically use `add` callback, but don't call submit method.

Comment: I have added to my question, where i get data is undefined when i add an onlclick handler. Any way to fix that ?

Comment: Add if statement `if (data) {...}`

Comment: Even on adding if i get data undefined

Comment: The way is shorter. Just add `autoUpload : false` option on init `$().fileupload(...)`. Remove from your add callback submit and onclick handler and add `$("#import_button").on('click', function () {  $('#import_form').triggerHandler('fileuploadsubmit') })`

Comment: As per your suggestion i have changed my code to https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7545762 . Is that correct ?. Its still not working though

Comment: Answer there. Let's continue discussion in your gist.